# Массив как свойство класса

Tags: массивы, objective-c, ios, классы

Здравствуйте, сейчас столкнулся с необходимостью по нажатии на кнопку добавлять объект в массив (массив - свойство класса), но судя по всему мой вариант не работает (объекты не добавляются).

**ARRViewController.m** *(функциональный фрагмент)*

```
- (IBAction)addClick:(id)sender {
ARRData *data = [[ARRData alloc] init];
[data.Array arrayByAddingObject:@"1"];
self.CountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)data.Array.count];
}
```

**ARRData.h**

```
@interface ARRData : NSObject

@property NSArray *Array;

@end
```

**ARRData.m**

```
@implementation ARRData

-(id)init{
self.Array = [NSArray new];
return self;
}

@end
```

После каждого нажатия кнопки в Array класса ARRData должен добавляться объект, а CountLabel должен показывать сколько объектов в массиве. Проблема в том что несмотря на количество нажатий, Label пишет 0

Comment: Не видно, у Вас массив инициализирован? Если нет то инициализацию массива вo -viewDidLoad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятных ошибок может быть несколько.

- при установке пропертей укажите свойства этих пропертей, например:

  @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Array;
- массив используйте мутабельного типа, в немутабельный кроме момента его инициализации Вы уже ничего добавить не сможете
- инициализируйте массив до начала его использования, например:

  -(void)viewDidLoad
  {
      _array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      [super viewDidLoad];
      ...
  }
- Для добавления в массив используйте методы `-addObject`  или `-insertObject:AtIndex:`
- непонятно почему вы обращаетесь к массиву как к члену только что созданного объекта `data`(хотя может так и нужно?), если массив глобален по отношению ко всему классу `ARRViewController` то и обращайтесь к нему `_array`

Comment: У меня идет обращение из ARRViewController в класс ARRData (NSObject). Для инициализации писал в ARRData.m

    -(id)init{
    self.Array = [NSMutableArray new];
    return self;
    }

подскажите как обратиться к массиву (@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Array;) из другого класса?  ARRData.Array не подходит

Comment: Вам почти точно [сюда][1]. И обратите внимание что происходит внутри метода `-init` это называется назначенный(designated) инициализатор.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/181303/objective-c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5

Comment: Именно там я и смотрел инициализацию массива:)
Сейчас вопрос стоит следующим образом: Как обратиться к нужному массиву для добавления в него объекта? (какой код должен выполниться в - (IBAction)addClick:(id)sender чтоб добавить объект (строку) в массив?)

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы массив был глобален ко всему проекту или только к этому классу в к `ARRViewController`у в котором Вы работаете? Если глобально для всего проекта, стоит ли необходимость иметь именно один экземпляр этого массива на весь проект?

Comment: Массив должен быть глобален ко всему проекту

Comment: Так используйте синглтон как и указано по ссылке, это именно Ваш вариант

Answer (score 1):

Используйте изменяемый масив NSMutableArray.
И не забудьте его проинициализировать.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто, что по вашему делает `[data.Array arrayByAddingObject:@"1"];` ? Вы похоже считаете что он меняет data.Array, но на самом деле он создает новый массив, в который входит объекты из вашего массива data.Array и добаленый объект, а data.Array каким был, таким и остается, вот он и пустой всегда. Вам уже правильно написали выше - используйте NSMutableArray и его метод addObject и  все будет хорошо